# What is the proper way to make Pydantic settings read .env variables with and without prefix when inheriting?

Tags: python, inheritance, config, pydantic, dotenv

I have this settings/config setup, the idea being to be able to switch between dev, test, prod, etc. configs easily, and I want the fields in BaseConfig to be loaded first, regardless of type of config, and then for the appropriately prefixed fields to be loaded.
However regardless of what I tried I couldn't get it to work.

My simplified setup

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class BaseConfig(BaseSettings):
    ENV_STATE: str
    SECRET_KEY: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=".env",
        extra="ignore",
    )


class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    DB_USERNAME: str
    DB_PASSWORD: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_prefix="DEV_",
        extra="allow",
    )


def get_config(env_state: str) -> BaseConfig:
    configs = {"DEV": DevConfig}
    return configs[env_state]()


config = get_config("DEV")

print(config.ENV_STATE)
print(config.SECRET_KEY)
print(config.ALGORITHM)
print(config.DB_USERNAME)
print(config.DB_PASSWORD)
```

And my .env looks like this

```
ENV_STATE="DEV"
SECRET_KEY = "gj5490ghj4569gj"

DEV_DB_USERNAME = "username"
DEV_DB_PASSWORD = "pass123"
```

When I run the code however, I get this error

> pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for DevConfig
> ENV_STATE
> Field required [type=missing, input_value={'DB_USERNAME': 'username...DB_PASSWORD': 'pass123'}, input_type=dict]
> For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
> SECRET_KEY
> Field required [type=missing, input_value={'DB_USERNAME': 'username...DB_PASSWORD': 'pass123'}, input_type=dict]
> For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing

So it seems to load only the prefixed fields, even with extra="allow", which is weird since if I give default values to ENV_STATE and SECRET_KEY in their definitions in BaseConfig it works, so it has no problem inheriting the values from BaseSettings, which DevSettings should only build on top of, yet it doens't want to get them from the .env file.

How do I make it work?